# How to bind tkinter filedialog to Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm writing a tkinter app that involves a lot of user input fields. One of these fields is a full file path, which is just begging for user error. In order to mitigate this, I'd like to program that particular Entry widget to call `filedialog.askopenfilename()` when clicked on, so that the user can just pick the file rather than entering the full path manually. As I understand it, the following code should do just that:

```py
# Minimalized version of my code that reproduces the problem
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog


parent = tk.Tk()
val = tk.StringVar()


def get_file(_):
    f = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    val.set(f)
    parent.focus()


label = ttk.Label(parent, text="Put your file here")
label.pack()
enter = ttk.Entry(parent, textvariable=val)
enter.pack()
enter.bind("<FocusIn>", get_file)

parent.mainloop()
```

When I run this and click on the Entry widget, `get_file()` gets called twice in a row. The second call comes immediately after I close the first file dialog and overwrites the first file I chose.

Why is this happening, and how do I stop it?

Thanks!

Comment: You say that you want it to appear when the user clicks in it, but you set it up to show the dialog when it receives focus. Those are two different  things. Which is the one that you actually want?

Comment: Changing Event type from "<FocusIn>" to "<Button>" seems to solve this issue

Comment: @BryanOakley: It was the former, but I had assumed that the "<Button>" event would have bound to a click anywhere on the app. In hindsight, that makes no sense, but then that's most assumptions. Thank you! :)